# Counting matrix entry subsets

Tags: combinatorics

I have a $n\times n$ matrix and I need to find how many sets of 4 entries (4 coordinate tuples) are there such that each entry in the set has exactly one other entry in its row and one in its column i.e. they form a "rectangle" in the matrix.

My idea was that we first choose 1 out of $n\times n$, then 1 out of the remaining $n\times n - 1$ and then we have no choice about the other 2 entries. Then, we divide this by the internal order of the choice as it doesn't matter. In summary, we get:

$$ (n \times n \times (n \times n-1) \times 1 \times 1) \div 4!$$

However, other people calculated this in a different way, multiplying the choices of rows and columns for the entries:

$$ {n \choose 2} \times {n \choose 2}$$

And the results are not the same by simply plugging in any value to n.

The  second method seems much clearer to me than mine, but I don't understand where my mistake is.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ideas  should work, but there are some minor mistakes you commited.

First choose one of the $n\times n$ entries in the matrix. Now choose another entry in **another column and another row** (there are $(n-1)^2$ such choices, and not $n(n-1)$ or $n^2-1$), so that we really have a rectangle. In fact, in this way you will be choosing two points in the diagonal of one of your rectangles.

This gives you $n^2(n-1)^2$ choices, but some of them give the same result. Namely, there are always $4$ different ways that you may obtain any of the rectangles inside your matrix, depending on the diagonal of the rectangle you take (2 choices), and the order of the points you take in that diagonal (also 2 choices). So you need to divide your original "number of choices" by $4$, and not $4!$.

Therefore the answer is $n^2(n-1)^2/4$, which is equal to $\binom{n}{2}\binom{n}{2}$.